# I killed Petrus, what do I do now?

Tags: dark-souls

I found out that Petrus, the guy who sells miracles in firelink, will kill the other miracle trainer. I had just started my paladin playthrough and so decided to buy out all the miracles I didnt have and then kill him, my reasoning being that when the other trainer appears I could continue to buy Miracles without worry, but now that she and her bodyguards have appeared they attack me.

Is there a way to stop them attacking me?

Ps. I just tried to absolve my sin with the guy at the bell tower. 20,000 souls and they still attack me.

Pps. Yeah so i just restarted it and haven't had any problems since.an annoying setback though it is i cant see a way around it.

Thanks to both who answered, you tried your hardest to help and i respect that. Your some cool dudes. (Or dudettes)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the other NPCs are attacking you is because you killed "another member of their order".

Normally, going to Oswald to "absolve your sins" should clear the slate, but I'm not sure why or if this should have worked.

Petrus has his own story line with the other three NPCs. Once you collect the Lordvessel, they will venture into the Tomb of the Giants, and get trapped. You can find them, kill the two guards (as they have gone hollow), then Reah will return to the Undead Chapel.

She will stay there for a short time (2 or 3 bosses), so you can buy miracles from her then. After that Petrus will kill her.

[Source](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Petrus+of+Thorolund)

The issue is that you unfortunately killed Petrus too early, so you have unfortunately ruined the story line for these characters. Ideally, you should kill Petrus *after* you rescue Reah from the Tomb of the Giants.

Unfortunately, I believe that since you killed Petrus before they arrived, they will be permanently aggro'd. The only way to resolve this is start the game over or enter ng+; or kill them.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this NPC friendly again - you need to request an Absolution from [Oswald of Carim](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Oswald+of+Carim).

Or you can just continue your game as is. Some Miracles are indeed only available from this NPC, but there are many others you can find somewhere else, see [Miracles](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Miracles). And if you want to collect all of them, you can always go to New Game Plus and complete your collection there.

Comment: After wasting 20,000 souls i went back to firelink and they are still attacking me. But thanks for answering surprised someone bothered.

Comment: @Bestusernameever oooops, sorry, it was supposed to help, I'm not sure what went wrong

Comment: Me either. Ive done it twice now, spending a total of 40,000 souls and still nothing.this is the remastered version and all so i have no clue why it would not work

Comment: Even if you're absolved of sin, Petrus is still dead, so Rhea is still hostile (or, hostile again). Any time an NPC becomes hostile because you kill another NPC, it's irreversible. This happens a handful of times throughout the game (I can think of three, maybe four off the top of my head, including this one).